# How to return from function nicely when multiple return values expected

Tags: python

The `myFunct` is expected to return two values. Both returned values are captured to `var_1, var_2`.

As an error check I am using a lot of `if/else: return` statement inside of scope of the function called (`myFunct` in this case). Typing simple `if arg<10: return` returns a **single** `None` which raises `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` since there are two variables: `var_1, var_2 = myFunct(5)` expecting two returned values but only a single value `None` is returned.

In order to avoid an error like this I would have to use a following syntax:

```
if arg<10: return None, None
```

which I find pretty ugly.

I wonder if there is a nicer way to do it...

```
def myFunct(arg):
    if arg<10:
        return
    return 100, 200

var_1, var_2 = myFunct(5)
```

Comment: If there's a problem, raise an exception.

Comment: I don't want to raise an exception. I just need to feed two None to var_1 and var_2 so they are happy.... but with a nicer syntax. By some reason I dislike `return None, None` syntax. But if there is no way around it I will take it as is.

Comment: I think it depends on what you later do with `var_1` and `var_2`. All of the solutions posted here are good, but which one is right probably depends on the greater context of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the result in a single variable then expand it as needed

```
result = myFunct(5)
var_1, var_2 = (None, None) if result is None else result
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! I've never realized a single variable can be used to catch a returned value: it doesn't matter a single or multiple are returned. If None is returned `result` is `None`. If two values are returned `result` is `tuple`. I just would never use var_1 and var_2 since `if result: then do this..`

Comment: Yes, `return a, b` is equivalent to `return (a, b)` - it returns a tuple of the values. The feature that allows you to view it as two separate values is called "unpacking" (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and works with any iterable - eg `a, b, c = xrange(3)`, or `a, b, c = '123'`

Answer (score 3):

If something is broken, the correct solution is to raise an exception. However, if you definitely don't want to do this, you could always:

```
try:
    var_1, var_2 = myFunct(5)
except TypeError:
    var_1, var_2 = (None,None)
```

Edit:

Perhaps you need to think about what you are going to do with your `var_1` and `var_2` if they are indeed None. If you are going to continue a calculation for which None is a valid input, then probably `return None,None` is the correct expression. If, however, this is an exception, and you are going to note that the result is None, and do something completely different (which does not have two values), then you can always do this:

```
result = myFunct(5)
if result:
    var_1,var_2=result
    do_more_stuff_here_with(var_1 and var_2) # logical and :)
else:
    print "myFunct(5) failed - check (and if necessary adjust) the phase of the moon"
```

Comment: This is nice as it fits with Python's "ask for forgiveness, not permission" idiom, however it does mask TypeErrors that are occurring within the function (rather than in the expansion).

Comment: And the way to solve that is to raise an exception within the function. Or, if it makes sense that both variables should return undefined values, `return None,None`. Both of these solutions have been specifically disallowed by the questioner.

Comment: I agree that returning `None, None` seems to make sense from the information supplied.

Answer (score 2):

While this is debatable, it's usually considered good practice to have a *single point of exit*. In other words, only one return statement. You can accomplish this as follows,

```
def myFunc(arg):
    result1, result2 = None, None
    if not arg < 10:
        result1, result2 = 100,200
    return result1, result2
```

Now obviously, your toy example is so simple there are even more pythonic ways you can simplify this *specific* example, such as:

```
def myFunc(arg):
    return (None, None) if arg < 10 else (100,200)
```

But the *single point of exit* is a good practice to get into for my complex functions.

And as others have pointed out, raising exceptions is the most pythonic way to signal that a function reached an error condition. `None` as a return should generally only be used to signal essentially the equivalent of an empty list, I.E. where getting nothing back is an expected possible outcome of the function.

Answer (score 2):

How about a lovely decorator?

```
import decorator

def default_return_value(value):
    @decorator.decorator
    def decorate(f, *args, **kwargs):
        x = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return value if x is None else x
    return decorate

def returns_tuple(size):
    return default_return_value(tuple([None] * size))

@returns_tuple(size=2)
def myFunct(arg):
    if arg >= 10:
        return 100, 200

>>> myFunct(15)
(100, 200)

>>> myFunct(5)
(None, None)
```

Comment: Interesting! A nice way to put it